# Android Studio with the same theme as IntelliJ on Windows

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio seems to have different "theme" on Windows than IntelliJ products I use (PhpStorm, etc.). I'd like to force AS to the more native look&feel. How to do it?

Android Studio 3.6:
[image]

PhpStorm 2019.3:
[image]

I've tried running AS with JetBrain's JDK, but still the same.

```
Android Studio 3.6
Build #AI-192.7142.36.36.6200805, built on February 12, 2020
Runtime version: 11-ea+102 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1979M
Cores: 12
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.jetbrains.ChooseRuntime
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you download Intellij IDEA and the Android SDK separately. That way Intellij IDEA will have the look and feel you are looking for.

You can find instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-android-development.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install "default" light theme found in phpstrom in android studio 3.6(latest)

Download IntelliJ Light Theme jar file(select compatibility as android studio) from this [website](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12697-intellij-light-theme/versions).

1. open android studio.
2. File -> Settings -> Plugin -> from the wheel drop down select 'Install Plugin from Disk....'

[image: install theme]

3. select IntelliJ Light Theme jar file.
4. Restart IDE.
5. Go to File -> Settings -> Appearance -> Theme, drop down select IntelliJ Light Theme and select Apply.

[image: select theme]

By this way you can install your favorite [themes](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?headline=164-theme&tags=Theme).

I hope this helps.